# How do I get fprintf to preserve space for an empty numerical value?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I'm using `fprintf` to print a list of numerical values under column headings, like so:

```
fprintf('%s %s %s %s\n', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')
for i = 1:length(myVar)
    fprintf('%8.4g %8.4g %8.4g %8.4g\n', myVar{i,1}, myVar{i,2}, myVar{i,3}, myVar{i,4})
end
```

This results in something like this:

```
    col1     col2     col3     col4
   123.5    234.6    345.7    456.8
```

However, when one of the cells is empty (e.g. `myVar{i,3} == []`), space is not preserved:

```
    col1     col2     col3     col4
   123.5    234.6     456.8
```

How do I preserve space in my format for a numerical value that may be empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the functions [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) and [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html) to change each cell to a string first, then print each cell as a string using [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html):

```
fprintf('%8s %8s %8s %8s\n', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4');
for i = 1:size(myVar,1)
  temp = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x,'%8.4g'),myVar(i,:),'UniformOutput',false);
  fprintf('%8s %8s %8s %8s\n',temp{:});
end
```

This should give you output like:

```
    col1     col2     col3     col4
   123.5    234.6             456.8
```

Notice also that I added eights to your first FPRINTF call to fix the formatting of the column labels and changed `length(myVar)` to `size(myVar,1)` since you are looping over the rows of `myVar`.